# Application callchain incomplete for perf record samples within glibc

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, glibc, perf

I want to get the callchain for my program using the `perf` tool. But the result is always incomplete, it always lacks the last function which directly invokes `usleep`. I have tried to record `sched:sched_switch`, and `usleep` trace events, but the result is always the same. Below is the command line:

```
$  g++ -g  -rdynamic test_sleep.cpp -o test_sleep
$ ./test_sleep &
$ ps -ef |grep test_sleep |grep -v grep
root     15292 14879  0 16:31 pts/1    00:00:02 ./test_sleep

$ perf record -e  probe_libc:usleep -e sched:sched_switch  -gp 15292
$ perf script 

test_sleep 15292 [019] 159309.652668:      probe_libc:usleep: (7ff615142030)

                   ee030 usleep (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
                    1039 funcs1 (/home/test_sleep)
                    1070 fun (/home/test_sleep)
                    107b main (/home/test_sleep)
                   21b15 __libc_start_main (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)

test_sleep 15292 [019] 159309.663728:     sched:sched_switch: test_sleep:15292 [120] S ==> swapper/19:0 [120]

            7fff8168dbb0 __schedule ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7fff8168e069 schedule ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7fff8168cf36 do_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7fff810b786b hrtimer_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7fff810b79ae sys_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7fff81699089 system_call_fastpath ([kernel.kallsyms])
                   bd410 __GI___libc_nanosleep (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
                    1039 funcs1 (/home/test_sleep)
                    1070 fun (/home/test_sleep)
                    107b main (/home/test_sleep)
                   21b15 __libc_start_main (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

Below is the code for my program:

```
void funcs2()
{
    for(i = 0; i< 100; i++){};
    while(1)
        usleep(10000);
}
void funcs1()
{
    for(i = 0; i< 100; i++){};
    funcs2();
}
void fun()
{
    for(i = 0; i< 100; i++){};
    funcs1();
}
main()
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

We can see `funcs2` is missing in the callchain. Is this function optimized by the `g++` compiler? But I do not use `-O` option and I catch the complete callstack using `backtrace_symbols` in my programs, below is the callstack recorded by `backtrace_symbol`:

```
./test_sleep(_Z6funcs2v+0x32) [0x400e4f]
./test_sleep(_Z6funcs1v+0x35) [0x401039]
./test_sleep(_Z3funv+0x35) [0x401070]
./test_sleep(main+0x9) [0x40107b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7ff615075b15]
./test_sleep() [0x400d59]
```

Comment: What an excellent first question for StackOverflow with a good description and code example (I'll condone the missing `int`s for now ;-)). I took the liberty to rephrase the title a little bit to make it easier to find.

Comment: Thank you, Zulan. This is the first question for StackOverflow. Next time I will pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 1):

By default `perf` uses frame-pointers to generate the callchain within userspace. Unfortunately frame-pointers are not reliable due to optimization. Your issue arises because your `glibc` is compiled with a specific optimization (`-fomit-frame-pointer`) which inhibits and easy stack unwinding.

Let's see what `perf` does. The in-kernel callchain is done with a different mechanism

```
        7fff8168dbb0 __schedule ([kernel.kallsyms])
        7fff8168e069 schedule ([kernel.kallsyms])
        7fff8168cf36 do_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
        7fff810b786b hrtimer_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
        7fff810b79ae sys_nanosleep ([kernel.kallsyms])
        7fff81699089 system_call_fastpath ([kernel.kallsyms])
```

The initial userspace entry uses the current userspace instruction pointer, so perf gets this right

```
               bd410 __GI___libc_nanosleep (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

Now perf uses the userspace frame pointer to determine the next function. Since `libc` didn't update the frame pointer due to the optimization. It gets the frame pointer of `funcs2` (instead of `__GI___libc_nanosleep`). The return address of `funcs2` points to `funcs2` - so that's what perf sees as next on the stack.

```
                1039 funcs1 (/home/test_sleep)
                1070 fun (/home/test_sleep)
                107b main (/home/test_sleep)
               21b15 __libc_start_main (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

So this has nothing to do with the optimization within your program. You're even lucky that `libc` at least left your frame-pointer intact so you continue to see the stack except for the topmost function.
That said, `perf` provides two other options for generating the callchain. `--call-graph=dwarf` actually stores a part of the stack and unwinds it with post-processing. On my system this shows `funcs2`, but nothing beyond that in userspace. There is also `--call-graph=lbr` which uses some hardware support of Intel CPUs. Unfortunately I can't test it.

This behavior affects any perf samples within libc, be it different events, syscalls or just hardware samples. For reference, see for instance this [debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767756) discussing a frame-pointer version of libc. You could of course build your own `libc` with frame-pointers.

Comment: Hi Zulan. What system are you using ? Centos or Ubuntu ? I remember glibc is optimized (-fomit-frame-pointer) by default. You said your result contains the funcs2, and how did you do that ?